# GNU/Linux: Open programm in Konsole / Term

Tags: linux, terminal, emacs, konsole

How can you run an application directly inside a Konsole (KDE) or Terminal (GNOME)?

I'm particularly interested in having a shortcut to Emacs:

`emacs -nw`

Being in KDE, that would open a Konsole and run Emacs (no-windows), and GNOME would run it inside a Terminal. I guess Konsole should have a parameter in which you can ask it to run, and open a certain program/script. Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Man pages are the best way to get this information, run "man konsole" and "man gnome-terminal".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`man gnome-terminal` tells me:

```
   -e, --command=STRING
             Execute the argument to this option inside the terminal.

   -x, --execute
             Execute the remainder of the command line inside  the  termi‐
             nal.
```